# Python not creating file

Tags: python

I'm trying to write to a text file in Python.  The file doesn't yet exist so I'm using:

```
def writeToTextFile(players):
    file = open('rankings.txt', 'a')
    for player in players:
        file.write(player.name, player.rating, player.school, '\n')
    file.close()
```

I used `'a'` for append and I thought it would create a new file (based on documentation).  I look on my desktop (where I'm running my script from) and there's no "rankings.txt" file to be found.

Any thoughts on how to fix?

Thanks,
bclayman

Comment: Check your Python install directory. Also, what are you doing about exceptions? Because `file.write` doesn't take arguments in the form you're passing them.

Comment: check it for...what?

Comment: Make sure there is data in your `players` container otherwise it's not going to end up writing anything.

Comment: @user2357112 isn't it placed in the same directory as my script by default?

Comment: @Kilenaitor players if full of player objects (i've just printed them all out)

Comment: @bclayman: Depends on how you're running it. It might not be running in the directory you think you're running it in.

Comment: Are you getting no errors on your `write()` function? I don't think `write()` takes more than one argument.

Comment: @user2357112 how might I determine my python install directory?

Comment: @Kilenaitor no errors on my write function, nope

Comment: Try putting `import os; print os.getcwd()` at the top of your script; that'll print out what directory your script is running in, and you can check that directory for the file.

Comment: Also, seriously, you need to figure out what's happening to the error that `file.write` call is throwing, or whether that line is even being executed. `file.write` does not work that way; it only takes one string.

Comment: @user2357112 it prints "/Users/bclayman/Desktop".  i replaced my line with "file.write("hey there", 'a')" and it still doesn't show up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for your `write` command is incorrect. The function only accepts a string as an argument. For example:

```
file.write("{}, {}, {}\n".format(player.name, player.rating, player.school))
```

---

I've mocked up a quick example of the full script to show this in action:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, rating, school):
        self.name = name
        self.rating = rating
        self.school = school

def writeToTextFile(players):
    f = open('rankings.txt', 'a')
    for player in players:
        f.write("{}, {}, {}\n".format(player.name, player.rating, player.school))
    f.close()


players = []
for x in range(5):
    name = 'Name {}'.format(x)
    rating = 100 - x
    school = 'School {}'.format(x)
    players.append(Player(name, rating, school))

writeToTextFile(players)
```

---

This script creates 5 `Player` objects and appends them to the `players` list. This is passed to your `writeToTextFile` function. It then creates the `rankings.txt` file in the location I am running the script from with the following output:

```
Name 0, 100, School 0
Name 1, 99, School 1
Name 2, 98, School 2
Name 3, 97, School 3
Name 4, 96, School 4
```

---

#### Changes or improvements to make:

- I changed the `file` variable to `f` to prevent shadowing the built in object with the same name.
- Another change you can make is using `with` instead of manually `open`ing and `close`ing your file objects.

This can be done like so:

```
with open('rankings.txt', 'a') as f:
    for player in players:
        f.write("{}, {}, {}\n".format(player.name, player.rating, player.school))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Even when I try to write a simple string such as "hey there" to the file, the file doesn't get created on my desktop.  I've adopted your syntax above (the last 3 lines) but I still don't see a file created on my desktop :(